# Solve a nonlinear system of coupled differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, coupling

I have this system of differential equations which describes the motion of a missile launcher model with 5 degrees of freedom:

(1)$$(m_w +m_v +m_p)\ddot{y}_w - (m_v + m_p)h_v\ddot{\vartheta}_w \sin(\vartheta_w) 
+ m_p \xi_p \ddot{\vartheta}_v \cos(\vartheta_v) \\
- (m_v + m_p)h_v\dot{\vartheta}^2_w \cos(\vartheta_w) 
- m_p\xi_p \dot{\vartheta}^2_v \sin(\vartheta_v) + m_p \dot{\xi}_p \dot{\vartheta}_v \cos(\vartheta_v) 
+k_{w11}\lambda_{w11} \\
+ k_{w12}\lambda_{w12} -c_{w11}\dot{\lambda}_{w11} -c_{w12}\dot{\lambda}_{w12} = -(m_w +m_v +m_p)g$$

(2)$$[I_w+I_{p_{zp}}+I_v+(m_v+m_p)h^2_v]\ddot{\vartheta}_w 
+ [I_{p_{zp}}+m_p h_v \xi_p(\cos\vartheta_w\sin\vartheta_v \\
- \sin\vartheta_w\cos\vartheta_v)]\ddot\vartheta_v 
- (m_v + m_p)h_v\ddot{y}_w \sin\vartheta_w - m_p h_v \ddot{\xi}_p(\cos\vartheta_w\cos\vartheta_v \\
+ \sin\vartheta_w\sin\vartheta_v) 
+ 2m_p h_v \dot{\xi}_p \dot{\vartheta}_w \sin\vartheta_w\cos\vartheta_v \\
-2m_p h_v \dot{\xi}_p \dot{\vartheta}_v \sin\vartheta_w\cos\vartheta_v 
+m_p h_v \xi_p \dot{\vartheta}^2_v(\cos\vartheta_w\cos\vartheta_v + \sin\vartheta_w\sin\vartheta_v)\\ +k_{w11}l_{w1}\lambda_{w11} + k_{w12}l_{w2}\lambda_{w12} - k_{w31}\lambda_{w31} 
-c_{w11}l_{w1}\dot{\lambda}_{w11}+c_{w12}l_{w2}\dot{\lambda}_{w12} \\
+ c_{w31}\dot{\lambda}_{w31} = (m_v + m_p)gh_v\sin(\vartheta_w+\vartheta_{wst})$$

(3)$$(I_v + I_{p_{zp}} + m_p\xi^2_p)\ddot{\vartheta}_v + m_p \xi_p \ddot{y}_w\cos\vartheta_v 
+ [I_v + I_{p_{zp}} + m_p h_v \xi_p(\cos\vartheta_w\sin\vartheta_v \\
- \sin\vartheta_w\cos\vartheta_v)]\ddot{\vartheta}_w + 2m_p\xi_p\dot{\xi}_p\dot{\vartheta}_v 
+ m_p h_v\xi_p\dot{\vartheta}^2_w(\sin\vartheta_w\sin\vartheta_v \\
+ \cos\vartheta_w\cos\vartheta_v)+k_{w31}\lambda_{w31}-c_{w31}\dot{\lambda}_{w31} = 
-m_pg\xi_p\cos(\vartheta_v + \vartheta_{vst})$$

(4)$$ m_p\ddot{\xi}_p-m_ph_v\ddot{\vartheta}_v(\cos\vartheta_w\cos\vartheta_v 
+ \sin\vartheta_w\sin\vartheta_v) \\
+ m_p\ddot{y}_w\sin\vartheta_w + m_ph_v\dot{\vartheta}^2_w(\sin\vartheta_w\cos\vartheta_v - \cos\vartheta_w\sin\vartheta_v) \\
+ m_p\xi_p\dot{\vartheta}^2_v = -m_pg\sin(\vartheta_v + \vartheta_{vst}) + P_p$$

(5)$$I_{p_{xp}}\ddot{\varphi}_p = M_p$$.

The scheme of the model is this: [scheme of the launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvzF7.png).

I know all the coefficients but I want to see the trend in the first 2 seconds of the variables $y_w, \vartheta_w, \vartheta_v, \xi_p, \phi_p$. Unfortunately I tried with Matlab ode45 but the system is coupled and nonlinear, can you suggest me a numerical method, a code, or anything that may help me solve this system?

After understanding the procedure I can do some more advanced calculations but I need to figure out the approach to solve it first. Thanks, really thanks, to anybody who wants to help.

Loris

EDIT: same equations but with numbers and with linearised sines and cosines so that you can clearly see where is the difficulty:

(1.1)$$\ddot{y}_w = 0.0917\ddot{\vartheta_w}\vartheta_w -0.1667\xi_p\ddot{\vartheta_w} +0.0917\dot{\vartheta_w}^2 + 
    0.1667\xi_p\dot{\vartheta_v}^2\vartheta_v -0.1667\dot{\xi_p}\dot{\vartheta_v} -4166.67(2y_w +0.3916\vartheta_w)+
    4.1667*(2\dot{y}_w +0.3916\dot{\vartheta_w}) + 9.81$$

(2.1)$$\ddot{\vartheta_w} = -0.3217\ddot{\vartheta_v} -0.4531\xi_p\ddot{\vartheta_v}(\vartheta_v-\vartheta_w)
    +1.2082\ddot{y}_w\vartheta_w +0.4531\ddot{\xi}_p(1+\vartheta_w\vartheta_v) 
    -0.9602\dot{\xi}_p\vartheta_w(\vartheta_w-\vartheta_v) -0.4531\xi_p\dot{\vartheta_v}^2(1+\vartheta_w\vartheta_v)
    -4.393\cdot 10^4y_w -1.72\cdot 10^4\vartheta_w +366(\vartheta_v-\vartheta_w) +21.5\dot{y}_w +21.78\dot{\vartheta_w} +36.6(\dot{\vartheta_w}-\dot{\vartheta_v}) +11.8529\vartheta_w$$

(3.1)$$\ddot{\vartheta_v} = -3.9734(\xi_p^2\ddot{\vartheta_v}+\xi_p\ddot{y}_w) -\ddot{\vartheta_w}
    -0.8197\xi_p(\vartheta_v-\vartheta_w)\ddot{\vartheta_w} -7.9468\xi_p\dot{\xi}_p\dot{\vartheta_v} -0.8197\xi_p\dot{\vartheta_w}^2(1+\vartheta_w\vartheta_v)
    -662.23(\vartheta_v-\vartheta_w) -66.223(\dot{\vartheta_v}-\dot{\vartheta_w}) +38.98\xi_p$$

(4.1) $$\ddot{\xi}_p = 0.2063\ddot{\vartheta_v}(1+\vartheta_w\vartheta_v) -\ddot{y}_w\vartheta_w
    -0.2063\dot{\vartheta_w}^2(\vartheta_w-\vartheta_v) -\xi_p\dot{\vartheta_v}^2 -9.81\vartheta_v +333$$

(5.1) $$\ddot{\phi}_p = 81$$

Comment: Can you make your equations less cumbersome? Like clubbing 3-4 constants into a single constant?

Comment: I'll put numbers directly:

Comment: If I am right all second derivatives appear linearly and you can express the system in the form $\ddot{ \mathbf z}=f(\dot { \mathbf z}, \mathbf z)$, which you can handle with a numerical ODE solver (Runge-Kutta).

Comment: @YvesDaoust do you mind showing a brief example taking for example eq 4.1? I think the problem is that derivatives are multiplied with other derivatives or functions like $\ddot{y}_w\vartheta_w$ or $\ddot{\vartheta_v}\vartheta_w\vartheta_v$

Comment: @gravinozzo: it doesn't matter. Solve the system for the second derivatives, taking their factors as mere coefficients (it's a $4\times4$ linear system.) Analytically you need to invert an ugly matrix, but in the numerical implementation you'll probably use Gaussian resolution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you are saying to solve something like $[A]{\ddot{x}}={B}$, I tried that approach with not too much success

Comment: @gravinozzo: "something like", "not too much success", can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 2):

Letting the four unknowns form the vector $\mathbf z$, your system can be written

$$\ddot{\mathbf z}=P(\dot{\mathbf z}, \mathbf z)\ddot{\mathbf z}+\mathbf q(\dot{\mathbf z}, \mathbf z)$$ where $P$ is a matrix and $\mathbf q$ a vector, both depending on $\dot{\mathbf z}$ and $\mathbf z$.

Solve this by

$$\ddot{\mathbf z}=(I-P(\dot{\mathbf z}, \mathbf z))^{-1}\mathbf q(\dot{\mathbf z}, \mathbf z).$$

Then with $\mathbb w=\dot{\mathbb z}$, you get a nonlinear system of the first order,

$$\begin{cases}
\dot{\mathbf w}=(I-P({\mathbf w}, \mathbf z))^{-1}\mathbf q({\mathbf w}, \mathbf z)\\\dot{\mathbf z}=\mathbf w
\end{cases}$$
ready for numerical resolution.

Comment: I will try this right away, thank you so much. Doesn't matter if the P matrix is not diagonal right? my P matrix has 1s on the diagonal and a lot of chaos elsewhere.

Comment: to build P and q should I put every element on one side in order to get eq1=0, eq2=0 etc and then take all the coefficients of $\ddot{z}$ to build P and all the rest will be q?

Comment: @gravinozzo: my post is very explicit about that.